# Embedded credentials alternatives for HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http, google-chrome-extension

A while ago I created a chrome extension called MalOnTheGo. It has been working well however chrome is now dropping support for the way I access resources from an API. The Chromestatus for the drop can be found [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856). They are dropping support for a format of urls called Embedded Credentials. I have looked for alternatives however I haven't been able to find anything.

In the API documentation they specify formatting the link in the same way I do using jQuery with the username and password parameters like this :

"Usage Examples:

CURL:

curl -u user:passwordhttps://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml

This is one of the code snippets that chrome is alerting me will not work at some point in June.

```
function verifyCredentials(username, password, error, success) {
                $.ajax({
                        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml",
                        "error": error,
                        "username": encodeURIComponent(username),
                        "password": encodeURIComponent(password),
                        "success": success
                });
        }
```

The API's documentation states that this is the way to access that resource. 
Is there anything I can change on my end or is this the only way I can use it and the API developers need to update their implementation?

Any alternatives to what I currently have would help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find CORS to be helpful for making a cross-domain request to verify credentials. There is a lot of helpful info in this tutorial:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You can still use ajax to make your request, you will just need to add some more headers for authentication. There is a section specifically for Chrome extensions as well:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cross-domain-from-chrome-extensions